# "Unicorns" button on Elections.SE needs an implementation!

Tags: bug, status-completed, unicorns, fun, election-page

On [Elections.SE](http://elections.stackexchange.com/), the footer contains a link which is masked by the word "unicorns". Disappointingly, upon clicking it, nothing happens. *(Browsing the source code, there appears to be an existing feature for this, but this currently has no effect in any browser.)*

[image: Look, you made the unicorn sad...]

I request that, upon clicking this button, a unicorn should fly across the screen. I am, of course, open to other ideas as well.

Comment: Works fine in my browser!  And it's *spectacular*

Comment: This is absolutely amazing freehand drawing. Tablet?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi The writing, yes. As for the unicorn... well, I know a guy.

Comment: Meta-meta-request: I think the next non-standard CSS revision should include a property for on-screen unicorns to make them alive, as in `-webkit-alive-unicorn` or something. This could then be applied to this button, so that a real unicorn would fly out of the browser.

Comment: +1 for freehand red circles.

Comment: @H2CO3 No. Not vendor prefixes. Please don't. Just use `alive-unicorn: true;`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try tapping it after selecting a site from the list ;)

Comment: But it's *really far away* after doing that...(Also, props for implementing it to begin with)

Comment: ^ This. Also, if you click it before opening a list, and then open a list, and then click it (many times), it's ineffective. :|

Comment: Defective unicorns are no fun :( Well no, actually, they're horses. But anyway..

Comment: I have such a pretty unicorn after doing this, I might have to change my gravatar.

Comment: Amazing. Just... amazing.